# Is 18-gauge wire sold as lamp cord sufficient for replacing the cord on a vintage toaster marked 6 amps?

Tags: wiring, appliances

I like my vintage toaster, but want to replace the cord.  I'd like to match the current cord, which is brown and cloth-wrapped.  Many lighting supply websites sell "parallel rayon-covered" cord that is 18-gauge 2-wire, but I haven't found a source of cord labeled for small appliances.  Will the lamp cord be sufficient?  The serial number plate on the toaster says

```
110-120V.-6A-NO.K-
```

Answer (score 3):

Electrically that would be fine, but possibly not thermally.  Most toasters I've seen have cords marked that they're special high temperature wiring.  I believe this is needed because the heat from the elements will conduct back along the cord (copper is a great conductor of heat as well as electricity), and it's important for the insulation not to melt.  It looks like the term to search for is "HPN cord"

Here's some examples of cords that are listed for high heat applications:
https://www.acehardware.com/departments/lighting-and-electrical/extension-cords-and-power-strips/power-cords/30127

[https://www.amazon.com/Power-cord-Heaters-Irons-Hardwired/dp/B000A8LL82](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000A8LL82)

Comment: Thank you!  The plug is the worst bit, maybe I will just replace that and leave the original cord.  Is there also a difference between replacement plugs labeled for appliances versus lighting (or not labeled)?

Comment: As far as I know there's not a difference in the plugs -- that should be far enough away that most of the heat from the elements won't reach there.

Comment: Thanks again!  I'll replace just the plug for now, and then keep an eye out for a better-condition cord to scavenge, like maybe an orphaned detachable one from a rice cooker or coffee pot.